# 301 redirection editing .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https

I set up SSL certificate and submitted to the hosting service. It says it is connected to Port. I wanted to redirect http url to https, so I edited .htaccess file with a code as below in the root folder through FTP. But it doesn't work. Can you give me an advice what to check to fix the problem? (my website address it https://tothealpha.com) Thanks!

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Lots of possibilities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267102/apache-htaccess-redirect-to-https-before-asking-for-user-authentication/26155051).